# Uses of 'after all', 'withal', 'anyway', 'anyhow' instead of 'however'?

Tags: word-usage, however-placement

Suppose, a sentence is: 'He isn't qualified on paper; however, the interviewer recommends to hire him based on his great potential.' Can I use 'after all', 'withal', 'anyway' and 'anyhow' instead of 'however' in this sentence?

Comment: What sort of sentence were you going to use them in?

Comment: _Withal_ is rather archaic; I don't recommend you to use it.

Comment: @KillingTime Please, see the edited question.

Comment: [The interviewer recommends he hire//recommend him to  hire is not grammatical]

Comment: @Lambie 'The interviewer recommends he hire, putting faith in his great ...' seems grammatical but very awkward-sounding to me.

Comment: Aha, anyway, it's: The interviewer recommends he be hired based on his great potential.....

Comment: @Lambie I didn't even consider that there was a glaring mistake. 'The interviewer recommends he be given the job of hiring, putting faith in his great ....' But note that it's your comment that I was addressing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Stop misrepresenting me! I did not say: The interviewer recommends he hire, putting faith in his great . You did. I was simply correcting the bit about "recommend  him to hire" which should be: recommend he hire or recommend he be hired, in terms of grammar. I was not editing the entire thing. Grrhh.

Comment: @Lambie 'The interviewer recommends him to hire'- here 'him' is an object. As far as I know that we should put 'him' as the object not 'he'. But you put 'he' instead of 'him' in that sentence. Please explain the grammatical rule you applied here. And can I say: 'The interviewer recommends manager  to hire him.' here?

Answer (score 1):

“Anyway” will change the tone, but you can use it in the end. As in “recommended to hire anyway”.

“Anyhow” means the same as anyway, but is informal.

“After all” usually indicates there were serious doubts. It is usable here but seems out of place. If it went like “he has a felony conviction and smells bad”, then “after all” would be justified.

If you want a viable alternative to “however” you could use “still” or “nonetheless”, or begin the sentence with “and yet.”

I cannot comment on “withal”. It is probably so archaic that I’ve never heard it.

Also. “Recommended *to hire him*”, not “him to hire”. Or *him to be hired*.

Answer (score 0):

Whether any of the words you suggest are apt alternatives to *however* depends on the sentence--its intended meaning, its syntax, and other stylistic choices.

Although we could multiply examples of how your alternatives to *however* could or could not work in a given sentence, perhaps a few representative sentences might clarify this issue.

> My doctor thought I should have the surgery. I, however, had a different idea.

- I, after all, had a different idea.
- I, withal, had a different idea.
- I, anyway, had a different idea.
- I, anyhow, had a different idea.

Clearly, none of your alternatives seems to work in the above sentences. They could be ***made*** apt, but the intended meaning of the sentence would need to change. For example,

> My doctor thought I should have the surgery. I felt differently. *After all*, I too am a doctor.

Here is, I suggest, an apt alternative to *however*:

> My doctor thought I should have the surgery. I, *on the other hand*, had a different idea.

Or to provide better parallelism, you could word the sentences as follows:

> *On the one hand*, my doctor thought I should have the surgery. I, *on the other hand*, had a different idea.

In short, the substitution of one word for another depends largely on the semantics of the sentence(s). Furthermore, I suggest your substitutes are of a different sort, semantically, than *however*.

Comment: Do I need to use 'on the one hand' at the beginning of the last sentence you have stated above?

Comment: @Md.HasibulHossain: No, not necessarily. To use it or to not use it is a stylistic decision on your part.